# How can I keep track of line numbers on an RTF Template using BI Publisher?

Tags: templates, xslt, rtf, peoplesoft, bi-publisher

I'm trying to output a line of text when I reach a specific line number on the output. Is there a function withing bi-publisher that will allow me to do that?

Comment: Have you tried a variable? https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12212/bip/BIPRD/GUID-C5A6173D-9D9A-47BD-9F8E-45A72B5E08A4.htm#BIPRD2532

Answer (score 0):

The function `position()` will give you the XML record number of the line you are on. You can do math and if statements on that.

You may also be interested in created a "group number" as I would call it. Where, in the data definition or SQL which is used to create the XML File, you create a field on the line level that increments by 1 for every X number of records. You can then use that in your template as a for-each-group grouping field.